# difference between remember and memorize

Tags: verbs

Do remember and memorize both work in the following sentences? I'm studying French.

> I often use pictures with French words to help me *remember* new words.

implies that I use these pictures to help me recall the French words.

> I often use pictures with French words to help me *memorize* new words.

implies that I use the pictures with words to commit the French words into my memory.

Answer (score 1):

*Remembering* something can be voluntary or involuntary (you can remember a bad experience that you would rather forget).

To *memorise* something is to commit it to memory deliberately.

Comment: Thank you. Do remember and memorise work in my OP?

Comment: Yes, because in this case the remembering _is_ voluntary.